# Maxima and Minima of multivariable functions:

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have got this two variable function $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)e^{-x-y}$ on the domain $0 \leqslant x\leqslant \infty$ and $0 \leqslant y\leqslant \infty$. I am supposed to find the maximum value of this function on the given domain. Now, if we convert the above equation into polar coordinates, we see that:
$$f(r,\theta)=r^2 e^{-r(sin\ \theta+\ cos\ \theta)}....(1)$$
The domain obviously changes from $r=[0,\infty)$ and $\theta=[0,\pi/2]$. Now, looking at this function,it is quite empirical that the maximum value occurs when $\text{sin}\ \theta\ + \text{cos}\ \theta$ is minimum. In the given domain, its minimum value is $1$. Thus the minimum value occurs at the boundaries of the given region. Now, to find at what distance it will occur, we differentiate the above function w.r.t. $r$ (remember we have now kept $\text{sin}\ \theta\ + \text{cos}\ \theta=1$). Therefore,
$$f_r(r,\pi/2)=2re^{-r}-r^2e^{-r}=0$$. From here we find that the $r=2$. Thus the minimum value comes out to be $4e^{-2}$.
But if we do not calculate the $\theta$ dependence empirically, things start to look a bit confusing to me. Differentiating $(1)$ w.r.t. $\theta$ directly and putting it to $0$ gives us $$r^3\mathrm{e}^{-r\sin\left({\theta}\right)-r\cos\left({\theta}\right)}\left(\sin\left({\theta}\right)-\cos\left({\theta}\right)\right)=0$$ giving us $\theta= \pi/4$. From this the minimum value comes out to be $2e^{-2}$.
Which part above is wrong? I'm having a hard time at figuring this out.

Comment: No reason to convert this into polar coordinates. Just stay in cartesian coordinates, differentiate and calculate the critical points. You should then take a look at $\partial [0, \infty]^2$.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, there is no reason to convert to polar coordinates.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that when you compute the derivative with respect to $\theta$, you are looking at values of $\theta$ inside $(0, \pi/2)$. You forgot to look at $\theta = 0$ and $\theta =\pi/2$

Comment: Just to emphasize @Peanut 's comment, try to figure out the maximum of $x^2$ on the $[-1,1]$ interval. The derivative is $0$ at $x=0$, but that's a minimum. Or find the minimum/maximum of $x^3$ over the same interval.